# How can I retrieve form data from Django CreateView?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a Django blog where the users can set the status of each post (active, inactive) when creating them. I am using Django's generic class-based views and would like to redirect the user to their created post only when the status is set to "active", otherwise they should be redirected to the homepage. How can I retrieve this submitted info from the form to create an if statement? For example: if status == "a"...

**views.py**

```
from .models import Listing
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'status', 'content']
    template_name = 'blog/post-form.html'
    success_message = 'Your post has been created.'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  "**redirect**" is not valid withing the method (form_valid) so you should definitely put something like def post, and get the value in request.data. I'm going to try showing you a code that is working for me in production. You let me know if it was the right response.

class LoginFormView(FormInvalidMessageMixin, LoginView):

```
template_name = "clientes/login.html

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    username = self.request.POST.get('username')
    password = self.request.POST.get('password')
    tipo_cuenta = self.request.POST.get('tipo-cuenta')
    tipo_cuenta = tipo_cuenta.strip()

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user:
        if has_group(user, 'admin'):
            messages.success(request, _('Not for admin'))
            return redirect('/login')

        cliente = Usuario.objects.filter(usuario=user).first()
        sucursal = Sucursal.objects.filter(usuario=user).first()
        empleado = Empleado.objects.filter(usuario=user).first()

        if tipo_cuenta == 'Punto afiliado':
            login(self.request, user)
            return redirect('/envios')
```